# React-Native Android Studio Project Build failed showing "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0."

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm working on a `React-Native` project and it is not building the project in Android Studio by showing the error `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0`

And the issue is accessing the file as it is showing `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

When I build the project, it shows the exception as under:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: E:\Project\android\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
43 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 41 up-to-date
```

Any solution on how to solve it? My project packages are as under:

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.59.9",
"react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.6.1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of my senior, when he tried to delete this file `E:\Project\android\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_:` it was unable to delete and showed the message that the file is already opened in `Java(TM) Platform SE Binary`. So simply open the Task Manager and end the task. Now the app is Building Successfully.